# Should access to a shared resource be locked by a parent thread before spawning a child thread that accesses it?

Tags: multithreading, locking, thread-safety, multicore, shared-memory

If I have the following psuedocode:

`sharedVariable = somevalue;`
`CreateThread(threadWhichUsesSharedVariable);`

Is it theoretically possible for a multicore CPU to execute code in threadWhichUsesSharedVariable() which reads the value of sharedVariable before the parent thread writes to it? For full theoretical avoidance of even the remote possibility of a race condition, should the code look like this instead:

`sharedVariableMutex.lock();`
`sharedVariable = somevalue;`
`sharedVariableMutex.unlock();`
`CreateThread(threadWhichUsesSharedVariable);`

Basically I want to know if the spawning of a thread explicitly linearizes the CPU at that point, and is guaranteed to do so.

I know that the overhead of thread creation probably takes enough time that this would never matter in practice, but the perfectionist in me is afraid of the theoretical race condition. In extreme conditions, where some threads or cores might be severely lagged and others are running fast and efficiently, I can imagine that it might be remotely possible for the order of execution (or memory access) to be reversed unless there was a lock.

Comment: My question concerns languages like C++, where you're close to the machine level, and where a "lock" is achieved using a simple InterlockedExchange loop.  

I'm concerned that declaring variables "volatile" is not enough to ensure synchronization.  

Isn't there a difference between "atomic" and "synchronized"? Atomic operations can't be split up — and if a variable is declared volatile, the compiler won't reorder accesses to it — but can't the CPU reorder them? Especially when accessed by different cores?

Comment: Additional clarification: In my example, "sharedVariable = somevalue" is used to pass data to threadWhichUsesSharedVariable. It is very important that threadWhichUsesSharedVariable only accesses "sharedVariable" after it has been assigned by the parent thread.

Comment: The CPU can only reorder the accesses if the reordering is not visible
to the program so CPU reordering should not be a concern. Much of the
complexity in designing multi-core system is in ensuring that the
programs never see a difference in behaviour from a single-core system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that your pseudocode is safe on any correctly functioning
multiprocessor system. The C++ compiler cannot generate a call to
`CreateThread()` before `sharedVariable` has received a correct value
unless it can prove to itself that doing so is safe. You are guaranteed
that your single-threaded code executes equivalently to a completely
non-reordered linear execution path. Any system that "time warps" the
thread creation ahead of the variable assignment is seriously broken.

I don't think declaring `sharedVariable` as volatile does anything
useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Given your example** and if you were using Java then the answer would be "No". In Java it is not possible for the thread to spawn and read your value before the assignment operation is complete.  *In some other languages this might be a different story.*

*"Variables shared between multiple threads (e.g., instance variables of objects) have atomic assignment guaranteed by the Java language specification for all data types except longs and doubles... If a method consists solely of a single variable access or assignment, there is no need to make it synchronized for thread-safety, and every reason not to do so for performance."*
[reference](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+performance+tuning/Chapter+10.+Threading/10.6+Atomic+Access+and+Assignment/)

If your `double` or `long` is declared `volatile`, then you are also guaranteed that the assignment is an atomic operation.

**Update:**  
Your example is going to work in C++ just like it works in Java. Theoretically there is no way that the thread spawning will begin or complete before the assignment, even with Out of Order Execution.

Note that your example is VERY specific and in any other case it is recommended that you ensure the shared resource is protected properly.  The new C++ standard is coming out with a lot of atomic stuff, so you could declare your variable as atomic and the assignment operation will be visible to all threads without the need of locking.  CAS (compare and set) is a your next best option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was really asking about C++ (or any language which puts you close to the machine level) and should have said so. I'll add a comment clarifying my question.

Comment: Thank you Lirik, and Per, both your answers have been helpful.